# HTML UTF-8 encoding

Tags: html

When I save in an editor (Notepad++) an HTML file as "utf-8" encoded the meta tag charset (=ISO-8859-2) seems to be ignored by browser (charset is always set to "utf-8", not matter which encoding i have set in meta tag)

What's more interesting when i save this doc as "ANSI" encoded file changing tag charset works...

Can You please explain me such a behaviour?

Comment: Probably the browser overrides the encoding meta tag if it detects utf-8 encoded file? If it is already utf-8 encoded, I don't think you need to change it to ISO-8859-2.

Comment: if the charset detection by the browser detectes the charset of the document as UTF-8 or saved with a BOM (ByteOrderMark), why it should trust your charset?

Comment: Why are you lying to the browser about the encoding of the file? Also, what Content-Type are you serving the file with?

Answer (score 1):

You can use META. Like this:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

"UTF-8" in Notepad++ really means "UTF-8 with [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)". The leading BOM very likely triggers UTF-8, regardless of what anything else is saying, since no other document should start with that particular byte sequence. Try saving as "UTF-8 without BOM" to see the difference.